# request.args.get method not throwing an error when the input argument is not of the specified type

Tags: python, flask

Why does the get method not throwing an error when the input argument is not of the specified type?

```
@app.route('/image', methods=['GET'])
def get_image():

    # Get args from GET request
    _id = request.args.get('id', type=int)
    return _id
```

http://127.0.0.0/image?id=Jon

Above API call returns a result.

I expected it to error out because the datatype of the id argument in "int".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask's request.args is a `MultiDict`. Below is the explanation of `type` paramater of get method of a multidict

> type – A callable that is used to cast the value in the MultiDict. If a ValueError is raised by this callable the default value is returned.

For more information read [here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get)

Comment: Ah, I was thinking if there is no default value specified, it will thrown an error.